# Cannot find -lgcc

Tags: python, gcc, cython, anaconda, conda

I am trying to follow an example for Cython builds from here http://blog.perrygeo.net/2008/04/19/a-quick-cython-introduction/, except my c1.pyx is simply helloworld.pyx with "print "Hello World"":

```
# this will create a c1.c file - the C source code to build a python extension
cython c1.pyx

# Compile the object file   
gcc -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.5/ c1.c

# Link it into a shared library
gcc -shared c1.o -o c1.so
```

The reason I am doing it in the command line is because my setup.py is giving me an error so I am doing it manually to see what is wrong.

The last step (gcc -shared c1.o -o c1.so) is where I hit the following error:

```
c:/users/MyName/anaconda/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
c:/users/MyName/anaconda/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit st
atus 1
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT1: Thank you @mat for the edit. Also, I was noticing I didn't have Visual C++ 2008 installed on my computer. Not sure if Anaconda requires this for GCC and if this is the solution.

Comment: Your `gcc`  is incorrectly installed.

Comment: Thank you @BasileStarynkevitch . As I am trying to use it with Conda, do you think there are issues with the communication? Or if I just install http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/, should I be fine? Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest using Linux, since most Linux distributions are packaging `gcc` .... I never used Windows or MinGw but I guess that your badly installed `gcc` would fail even on a trivial `helloworld.c`

Comment: I'm building a package for OSX, Linux and Windows in Python and it requires the GSL library and hence Cython/GCC in Windows. I'm hoping theres a way in Windows. Thanks for your help! @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: I've realized that Conda uses GCC from the C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda\MinGW\bin folder. But I still get this error when I believe it should recognize the GCC from there, right?